How to calculate the output impedance of a gain-boosted biasing circuit

I've been working on calculating the output impedance \$R_{Out}\$
​of the gain-boosted biasing circuit shown in picture, where all transistors are in the saturation region. While I understand the general approach involves using the small-signal model and considering the effect of the gain-boosting stage, I am having difficulty applying these concepts specifically to this circuit. Could you provide some guidance or steps on how to correctly calculate \$R_{Out}\$ for this circuit?
This cascode is so complicated that I'm not sure where to start. Do I have to calculate output Impedance by drawing 7 small signals in all of these?!Is looking into the inside of the amplifier required for calculating output resistance?

Is it correct that Route becomes A1gm2ro2ro1 with the same structure as this picture? If so, how do I get A1?

Please show an attempt at a solution

Rout is the impression viewed from the Drain part of M2.

You have to calculate the resistance seen by source of M2. Calculate reflected resistance towards drain of M2 . Resistance of gate of M3 is infinity. It can be neglected. Your only other resistance seen is that of drain of M1
